# snowflakeSql/ recursive computation

Tags: recursion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to make recursive computation with row_number function and specific recursive computation two colums: prob_reabo and prob_reabo_CUM

| rn | prob_reabo_cond | prob_reabo | prob_reabo_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 |
| 2 | 0.193382786 | 0.135854371 | 0.4333390446 |
| 3 | 0.1212333515 | 0.0686982068 | 0.5020372514 |

```
example 0.0686982068 = (1-0.4333390446)*0.1212333515
```

correct calculation:

[image]

I have got the code as follows:

```
WITH recursive BAZA AS ( 
    SELECT
        dat_fin_abo, plateforme, duree, statut_aae, 
        nv_recrute, jour_aae, tranche_mois_aae, 
        nb_aae, delai, dat_courante, prob_reabo_cond,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  dat_fin_abo, plateforme, duree, statut_aae, nv_recrute, jour_aae, tranche_mois_aae ORDER BY delai) as rn
    FROM 
        mya_fcst_prob_reabo
        where dat_fin_abo = '2023-01-31' 
            and dat_courante <= '2023-02-16' 
            and statut_aae = 'Repeaters' 
            and plateforme = 'DTH'
), MODELOWANIE AS (
    SELECT
      dat_fin_abo, plateforme, duree, statut_aae, nv_recrute, jour_aae, tranche_mois_aae, nb_aae, delai, dat_courante, prob_reabo_cond,
      RN, prob_reabo_cond prob_reabo, prob_reabo_cond prob_reabo_CUM
    FROM BAZA 
    WHERE 1=1 AND RN = 1
    
    UNION ALL    

    SELECT
      dat_fin_abo, plateforme, duree, statut_aae, nv_recrute, jour_aae, tranche_mois_aae, nb_aae, 
      A.delai, A.dat_courante, A.prob_reabo_cond, A.RN,
      (1-B.PROB_REABO_CUM)*A.PROB_REABO_COND prob_reabo,
      B.PROB_REABO_CUM+(1-B.PROB_REABO_CUM)*A.PROB_REABO_COND prob_reabo_CUM
    FROM
      BAZA A
      JOIN MODELOWANIE B USING (dat_fin_abo, plateforme, duree, statut_aae, nv_recrute, jour_aae, tranche_mois_aae, nb_aae)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND A.RN-1 = B.RN
) --CYCLE RN set is_loop to 'Y' default 'N'

SELECT * FROM MODELOWANIE ;
```

produced bad result:

| rn | prob_reabo_cond | prob_reabo | prob_reabo_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 |
| 2 | 0.193382786 | -0.381901363731 | -0.084416690131 |
| 3 | 0.1212333515 | 0.223574534171 | 0.13915784404 |

The question is: what did i do wrong (?)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

### Bug repo:

It seems there is bugs in Snowflakes recursion:

```
with baza as ( 
    select
        column1 as dat_fin_abo, 
        column2 as delai, 
         
        column3 as prob_reabo_cond,
        row_number() over (partition by  dat_fin_abo order by delai) as rn
    from values 
    (100, 10, 0.2974846736),
    (100, 11, 0.193382786),
    (100, 12, 0.1212333515)

), modelowanie as (
    with recursive rec_cte as (
        select
          b.dat_fin_abo, 
          b.delai, 

          b.prob_reabo_cond,
          b.rn, 
        
          0.0 as x2,
          0.0 as x1,
          
          b.prob_reabo_cond as prob_reabo, 
          b.prob_reabo_cond as prob_reabo_cum,
          1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cond as onemprob_reabo_cum
          
        from baza as b
        where b.rn = 1
    
        union all    

        select
            a.dat_fin_abo, 
            a.delai,

            a.prob_reabo_cond, 
            a.rn,
            
            b.prob_reabo_cum as x2,     
            (1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cum) as x1,
            
            b.onemprob_reabo_cum * a.prob_reabo_cond,
            b.prob_reabo_cum + (b.onemprob_reabo_cum * a.prob_reabo_cond),
            0
            //1.0 - (b.prob_reabo_cum + (b.onemprob_reabo_cum * a.prob_reabo_cond))
        from baza as a
        join rec_cte as b 
            using (dat_fin_abo)
        where a.rn-1 = b.rn
    )
    select * from rec_cte

)
select * from modelowanie ;
```

gives:

| DAT_FIN_ABO | DELAI | PROB_REABO_COND | RN | X2 | X1 | PROB_REABO | PROB_REABO_CUM | ONEMPROB_REABO_CUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 0.2974846736 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 | 0.7025153264 |
| 100 | 11 | 0.193382786 | 2 | 0.2974846736 | -28.74846736 | 0.135854371027 | 0.433339044627 | 0 |
| 100 | 12 | 0.1212333515 | 3 | 0.433339044627 | -42.3339044627 | 0 | 0.433339044627 | 0 |

which shows the first row, the math for `1.0 - value` is correct, but when done on the next row, for some reason the result is `* 100` which is super broken, and if you replace the 0 with the commented out line, that math on the "current recursion" also explodes..

swapping to the second:

```
            //0
            1.0 - (b.prob_reabo_cum + (b.onemprob_reabo_cum * a.prob_reabo_cond))
```

gives:

| DAT_FIN_ABO | DELAI | PROB_REABO_COND | RN | X2 | X1 | PROB_REABO | PROB_REABO_CUM | ONEMPROB_REABO_CUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 0.2974846736 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.2974846736 | 0.2974846736 | 0.7025153264 |
| 100 | 11 | 0.193382786 | 2 | 0.2974846736 | -28.74846736 | 13.585437102693 | 13.882921776293 | -12.882921776293 |
| 100 | 12 | 0.1212333515 | 3 | 13.882921776293 | -1,387.2921776293 | -156.183978405233 | -142.30105662894 | 143.30105662894 |

I would open a bug report. (I opened a bug)

but it's a typing problem..

### Cast things to Double:

```
with baza as ( 
    select
        column1 as dat_fin_abo, 
        column2 as delai, 
         
        column3 as prob_reabo_cond,
        row_number() over (partition by  dat_fin_abo order by delai) as rn
    from values 
    (200, 10, 0.2974846736),
    (200, 11, 0.193382786),
    (200, 12, 0.1212333515)

), modelowanie as (
    with recursive rec_cte as (
        select
          b.dat_fin_abo, 
          b.delai, 

          b.prob_reabo_cond::double,
          b.rn, 
        
          b.prob_reabo_cond::double as prob_reabo, 
          b.prob_reabo_cond::double as prob_reabo_cum
          
        from baza as b
        where b.rn = 1
    
        union all    

        select
            a.dat_fin_abo, 
            a.delai,

            a.prob_reabo_cond::double, 
            a.rn,
            
            ((1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cum) * a.prob_reabo_cond)::double,
            (b.prob_reabo_cum + ((1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cum) * a.prob_reabo_cond))::double
        from baza as a
        join rec_cte as b 
            using (dat_fin_abo)
        where a.rn-1 = b.rn
    )
    select * from rec_cte

)
select * from modelowanie ;
```

you get :

[image]

And thank you for teach me a new way to write recursive CTE's:

```
with recursive baza as ( 
    select
        column1 as dat_fin_abo, 
        column2 as delai, 
         
        column3 as prob_reabo_cond,
        row_number() over (partition by  dat_fin_abo order by delai) as rn
    from values 
    (200, 10, 0.2974846736::double),
    (200, 11, 0.193382786::double),
    (200, 12, 0.1212333515::double)

), modelowanie as (
    select
      b.dat_fin_abo, 
      b.delai, 

      b.prob_reabo_cond,
      b.rn, 
    
      b.prob_reabo_cond as prob_reabo, 
      b.prob_reabo_cond as prob_reabo_cum
      
    from baza as b
    where b.rn = 1

    union all    

    select
        a.dat_fin_abo, 
        a.delai,

        a.prob_reabo_cond, 
        a.rn,
        
        ((1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cum) * a.prob_reabo_cond),
        (b.prob_reabo_cum + ((1.0 - b.prob_reabo_cum) * a.prob_reabo_cond))
    from baza as a
    join modelowanie as b 
        using (dat_fin_abo)
    where a.rn-1 = b.rn
)
select * from modelowanie ;
```

Comment: it still gives me the same values not corrected like above, so recursion not works fine. Do you see any other reason (?)

Comment: you can also cast to fixed point `::number(30,10)` in the CTE to get correct results, OR if you cast the input values to double in the `baza` CTE you also get correct results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has started to work fine with double data type. Thank You indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to connect dots in an unexpected way when using recursion. Please, take a look at my simplified prototype code below.

Setup (Expected values are included in the data for easy verification):

```
create or replace temporary table t
(
    rn int,
    prob_reabo_cond number(20,10),
    prob_reabo number(20,10),
    prob_reabo_cum number(20,10)
)
;

insert into t
values
(1, 0.2974846736, 0.2974846736, 0.2974846736)
,(2, 0.193382786, 0.135854371, 0.4333390446)
,(3, 0.1212333515, 0.0686982068, 0.5020372514)
;
```

Recursive query (the last two columns on the output are calculated values):

```
with
recursive a (rn, prob_reabo_cond, prob_reabo, prob_reabo_cum, calculated_prob_reabo, calculated_prob_reabo_cum) as
(
    select
        rn
        ,prob_reabo_cond
        ,prob_reabo
        ,prob_reabo_cum
        ,prob_reabo_cond
        ,prob_reabo_cond
    from
        t
    where
        rn = 1
    union all
    select
        t.rn
        ,t.prob_reabo_cond
        ,t.prob_reabo
        ,t.prob_reabo_cum
        ,(1-a.calculated_prob_reabo_cum)*t.prob_reabo_cond
        ,a.calculated_prob_reabo_cum + t.prob_reabo
    from
        a
    join
        t
    on
        t.rn = a.rn+1
)
select * from a
;
```